# Substring check in Ruby on Rails controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, controller, web-scraping, substring

In my Ruby on Rails application, I have created a String array @dates from an HTML document.  I would like to extract the first element of @dates containing "Week of", save it in a separate variable @cal, and print it in the view.  Here is the controller method that would do this:

```
def locations
  page = Nokogiri::HTML(open("app/views/home/file.html"))
  @dates = page.css(".boxx")
  @cal = "THIS DOESNT WORK"

  @dates.each do |d|
    if d.include? "Week of" 
      @cal = d
      break
    end
  end
```

My problem is that even though "Week of" appears as text in the HTML document, I'm still getting "THIS DOESNT WORK" when I print @cal in the view.  For some reason, include? is not finding the substring match.  I'm not sure why.  Thanks so much for your help.

Comment: Have you printed out the value of `@dates`?

Comment: Yes, that value is normal.

Comment: For my future reference in asking this type of question, if I'd said "Have you printed out `@dates.inspect`, would you have answered differently?

Comment: I did not use .inspect but was loading @dates in the view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That happens because as per the code, "d" is not string but an object of type Nokogiri::XML::Element

You can try out following modification

```
  page = Nokogiri::HTML(open("app/views/home/file.html"))
  @dates = page.css(".boxx")
  @cal = "THIS DOESNT WORK"

  @dates.each do |d|
    if d.to_s.include? "Week of" 
      @cal = d
      break
    end
  end
```